# ireport versions

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have reports in the older version of IReport 2.x and I want to upgrade to the latest version. I want to switch between versions. Any easy way to do that?. Can anyone let me know the easiest way?

TU

Answer (score 0):

In iReport 'Preferences', check the '**Compatibility**' options under 'General' tab.

Comment: Thanks bchetty. Last available version is what I have there.

Comment: Select the version that you need, make some small change (which you can roll it back to the original, later) and try to save and compile it.